# Google Maps React, adding markers with lat lng

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Im using "google-maps-react" and trying to add new markers to my map with clicks.

I currently manage to console log the specific latLng, but cant seem to make a new one. I'm pretty new to React.

My onMapClick works with finding the latitude and longitude. But I think I need to add the position to an array and then use that one to update the map. Might be wrong

```
  onMapClick = (map,maps,e) => { 
    const { latLng } = e; 
    const latitude = e.latLng.lat(); 
    const longitude = e.latLng.lng(); 
    console.log(latitude + ", " + longitude);  

    var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      setMap: map,
    });
  }
```

The solution Im currently on is that I just hardcoded some Markers in my render() with the location of array in Marker

```
   <Marker
      onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
      name={storedLocations[0]}
      position={{lat:listLatitude[0], lan:listLongitude[0]}}
    />
```

My InfoWindow is:

```
<InfoWindow
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
       onClose={this.onClose}
     >
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
      </div>
    </InfoWindow>
  </Map>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My onMapClick works with finding the latitude and longitude. But I
>   think I need to add the position to an array and then use that one to
>   update the map.

That's indeed would the React way but instead of instantiating markers via Google Maps API, consider to keep the data (marker locations) via `state` and React will do the rest like this:

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locations: []
    };
    this.handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleMapClick = (ref, map, ev) => {
    const location = ev.latLng;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      locations: [...prevState.locations, location]
    }));
    map.panTo(location);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="map-container">
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          className={"map"}
          zoom={this.props.zoom}
          initialCenter={this.props.center}
          onClick={this.handleMapClick}
        >
          {this.state.locations.map((location, i) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={i}
                position={{ lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `locations` state is used to track all the locations once the map is clicked
- `locations` state is passed to Marker component to render markers

The next step could be to introduce a *separate* component for markers list, [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy) tells about components the follows:

> One such technique is the single responsibility principle, that is, a
>   component should ideally only do one thing. If it ends up growing, it
>   should be decomposed into smaller subcomponents.

```
const MarkersList = props => {
  const { locations, ...markerProps } = props;
  return (
    <span>
      {locations.map((location, i) => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            {...markerProps}
            position={{ lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </span>
  );
};
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ksphwy) which demonstrates how to add a makers on map click via `google-maps-react` library